# What exactly is the 'proximity profile' with respect to the Bluetooth Low-Energy APIs?

Tags: ios, ios5, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am currently developing an iOS app for a BLE device which will implement the `Proximity Profile` (which I currently don't have access to yet), but I am at a loss as to *what* that actually means.

I have read [the pdf document from bluetooth](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bluetooth.org%2Fdocman%2Fhandlers%2Fdownloaddoc.ashx%3Fdoc_id%3D239392&ei=7dqvUa6BDeWCiAKn74HoAg&usg=AFQjCNFEqeNKjXxDQzB7e9pJ2pcTnYEYKg&bvm=bv.47534661,d.cGE), and know that the BLE device would be the `proximity reporter` and the application the `proximity monitor`, but what does that mean in terms of the `CoreBluetooth` framework?

After connecting to a BLE device, the method I am currently using to measure proximity is through calls to `readRSSI` on the peripheral device. Does a device which implements the proximity profile behave differently so that I don't need to make that call? There isn't much documentation around to give a better idea.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but my impression is that it's simply:  if they're connected the device is within proximity.  If the device travels too far away and loses the connection an alarm goes off.  I don't think it has anything to do with the signal strength level, simply connected or not connected.

Comment: That is also my current level of understanding. The `CoreBluetooth` framework has a number of delegate functions, among which is `CBCentralManager:didDisconnectPeripheral:error`, where an alert could be triggered. I'm wondering if that's it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a description of the GATT services related to the proximity profile:  http://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/profiles/Pages/ProfileViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.profile.proximity.xml

It looks like it allows for an attribute to read the RSSI from (I think normally you can read that value from a lower level method directly from the transmitter/receiver).  So you should be able to read the RSSI value on both ends of the connection.

The profile also allows for alerts to happen on both ends and you can control what level of alert occurs.

I think essentially, a "profile" is just a collection of attributes in GATT.  If you have the required attributes you can state that you support that particular profile.

Here's a PDF with the little details if you want:  https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=239392

Comment: Thanks, the first link really clarified things a bit. So do you think that `org.bluetooth.service.tx_power` is what enables the app to read the RSSI without directly contacting querying the BLE device?

Comment: No, that's a GATT value.  You need to connect to the device and request that attribute to read it.  You should be able to get an RSSI value by communicating on a lower-level with the bluetooth hardware on the host device.  I'm not familiar with iOS so I wouldn't know how you'd do that specifically.